# .net core authentication hide password from developer tools

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I am using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity to implement basic system Login/Logout.

Here is a part of my code:

```
 [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginVM login, string returnUrl=null)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return View(login);

        var foundUser = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(login.EmailAddress);
        if (foundUser != null)
        {
            if (!await _userManager.IsEmailConfirmedAsync(foundUser))
            {
                ViewBag.Message = "Your credentials are wrong or your account is not activated.";
                return View(login);
            }
        }
        else return RedirectToAction("Register", "Account");

        var result = await _signinManager.PasswordSignInAsync(
            login.EmailAddress,
            login.Password,
            login.RememberMe,
            false);


        if (!result.Succeeded)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("Login error - please try again or contact support team.", "");
            return View(login);
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(returnUrl))
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");

        return Redirect(returnUrl);
    }
```

It works pretty good although, I can see my passwords on Headers through Network tab(Google Chrome developer tools).

[image]

Is there a way to avoid that? Can those credentials been hidden somehow?

Any help is welcome

Comment: Who exactly are you trying to hide this from? Right now, it's only the person who typed the password in that can use the dev tools. (assuming your website will be deployed with SSL)

Comment: Welcome to the world of HTTP. This is how it works. If you open a debugging tool [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) you'll be able to see all of the information that is posted from your pages. I highly recommend to gain some basic understanding of how HTTP works - that will save you a lot of headaches in the future.

Comment: Thank you @trailmax

Answer (score 2):

When submitting a form, the input data will be visible to the user entering it. However, it will be encrypted in transit if you use https.
Technichally you can use javascript to obfuscate it, but it will not increase security.